# Why do ANSI and UNICODE make it difficult to read and write texts using streams?

Tags: java, unicode, java-stream, ansi

I've learned that Reader and Writer in java are better for reading and writing information from text resource, and Reader/Writer are character-based while streams are byte-based. 
However I've come across a source that said "some texts are coded by ANSI oder Unicode. ANSI requires code conversion and Unicode can be coded in different formats like UFT-8 or UFT-16. Therefore Reader/Writer are better".

Do these code conversion and different formats have anything to do with text resource? Hence, what can Reader and Writer do that makes them better than streams at dealing with texts?

Comment: Readers and Writers present to their clients as streams of *characters*, whereas InputStreams and OutputStreams present as streams of *bytes*.  As a practical matter, then, the former can (and must) handle character encoding internally, whereas the latter require the user to handle such issues.  As a design principle, when the data you are dealing with are fundamentally textual (i.e. characters) the former provide the more appropriate abstraction.

Comment: This is probably too broad for stack overflow, but there's a really good writeup [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) on the difference between a byte stream and a character stream, and why there are different encodings.

Comment: @yshavit thanks for sharing this.

Comment: ANSI? Do you mean *ASCII?*

Answer (score 0):

When java was designed it was decided to hold **text** inside java as Unicode, so all scripts, say Greek and Korean might be combined.

Unicode is a numbering of all symbols (*code points*), and can be coded by UTF-8 (multi-byte, most compact in general), UTF-16 LE/BE (2 bytes) or even UTF-32.

So internally `String` constants in a .class are in UTF-8. The type `char` is 2 bytes for UTF-16. And String holds an array of `char`.

**Binary data**, like `byte[]` or `InputStream/OutputStream` could be text. But to interprete it as *text* one needs to know the encoding/charset of those bytes. Hence there always is a conversion of bytes and some charset of those bytes to the internal Unicode (UTF-16).

To answer the question, *it is unavoidable to somehow provide the charset of the binary data.* That is a defect of binary data.

When one reaches `String, char, Reader, Writer` one already operates entirely on Unicode text.

Bridging classes are `InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter` and `Files` provides some nice utility functions.

Compare this situation with C, where unsigned char might be the same as a byte (or not), and a wide char might be usable or not. Java did this better than some languages. However a Java programmer with C/C++ background should never ever use `String` or `char[]` for binary data: double memory, non-undoable and corrupting conversion. Rather `byte[], ByteArrayOutputStream, ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Internally they are [UTF-16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4). Binary data does not *have* a charset, and that is not a 'defect of binary data'.

Comment: @EJP: In Java 9, Java strings may internally be ISO-8859-1 instead (see [JEP 254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)), if it is more compact in memory than UTF-16 without losing any data. But the public interface would still have to represent UTF-16 for backwards compatibility, so for *all intents and purposes* treat Java strings as UTF-16 regardless of internal representation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I already forgot that. Thanks. But the claim remains "all Unicode is possible". ISO-8859-1 is one of the always provided Charsets: StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1. It is a limited Latin-1. It is a valuable but corner-case optimisation. At that time in history UTF-16 chars were thought to cover all feasible characters. Nowadays a UTF-16 char might be considered obsolete; one should consider processing _code points_ instead. So yes alternative encodings merit.

Comment: @JoopEggen: "*At that time in history UTF-16 chars were thought to cover all feasible characters.*" - a small correction, UCS-2, not UTF-16.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, that would be the better term, I know one or an other database still uses UCS-2. _(I'll write my memoires in EBCDIC.)_